# Правильно ли предложение по смыслу?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, редактура

*Они рассказали, какие тайны хранят деревья у озера, и что за ними скрывается...*

Скажите, пожалуйста, понятно ли, что "ними" относится к деревьям, а не к тайнам? И как лучше написать?

Comment: Это не форум редакторов и не то место, где вам будут отвечать, если вы после ответа удаляете вопросы.

Comment: Да? Я не знал, что нельзя удалять вопросы! Просто побоялся, что мои невообразимой красоты предложения, могут украсть писатели ( такие как Донцова, Стивен Кинг и т д) для своих книг!

Comment: Вопросы иногда можно удалять, но если там нет комментариев. Вам же уже ответили, стали обсуждать сказанное, а вы удалили всё.  Теперь о вашем предложении.  Вообще говоря,  предложение надо всегда давать полностью, иногда даже желательно с контекстом. Если у вас многоточие обозначает конец предложения, то непонятна суть последней фразы (по смыслу она ничего не добавляет к сказанному).  Также местоимение «ними» можно отнести к обоим существительным.  Дело даже не в том, что трудно разобраться, что к чему относится.  Само наличие неопределенности ухудшает качество текста.

Comment: Как лучше написать? Для этого нужен контекст.  Одно предложение можно записать просто: Они рассказали, какие удивительные тайны хранят деревья у озера.

Comment: Вот это красиво! Спасибо!